# Which regression model for S shaped fit curve?

Tags: regression

I am trying to build regression model for Outcome variable (WS) which is continuous, but limited in range from 0 to 100. My predictor (ASA) is also continuous but going from 0 with no upper limit.

In consequence my data follows something like logarithmic or S shaped curve and are obviously not appropriate for lm model.

Do you have any suggestions on how to model it? and maybe hints for respective R functions
[image: Scatter plot]

Comment: you can try the excelent `rms` package by @frankharrell for the Spline Regression! Or the first thing you can try is to take the $log(WS)$ as response variable.

Comment: `WS` looks decidedly discrete, rather than continuous.  This suggests it might be derived from some other variables, such as counts.  Could you explain what `WS` is and how it was measured?  @Metariat Taking the logarithm will make the heteroscedasticity worse, not better.  In general it's more important to choose a model appropriate for the error structure and then deal with nonlinearity in the response.  Here, it looks likely that a GLM could go a long way--splines might not even be necessary.

Comment: @Materiat I will try the rms package, great suggestion. However the log(WS) doesn't really help, still far away from normal distribution

Comment: @whuber, I agree that it seems to be discrete even if it shouldn't. WS is geographical measure of accessibility of services, whereby every service contribute to the WS proportionally to the importance of service and inversely proportionally to its distance. The individual observations are equally distributed. I will have a detailed look at the strange patterns in the scatter plot, thanks for your comment!

Comment: You could also have a look at ordinal regression, search this site